# IIS 10 Url Redirection fails only when browsing single domain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I manage two domains, matiasmasso.es and matiasmasso.pt
Next rules are set on my Web.Config, and they work Ok for almost all of the urls
The exception is when calling http://www.matiasmasso.pt (no SSL to hit the rule) it is wrongly redirected to https://www.matiasmasso.es
It does not happen if the url appends any segment like http://www.matiasmasso.pt/test it successfully opens https://www.matiasmasso.pt/test.

Here are my rules:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
      
      <rule name="RedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>

      <rule name="RedirectNonWwwEsToWww" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^matiasmasso.es$"  ignoreCase="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.matiasmasso.es/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>

      <rule name="RedirectNonWwwPtToWww" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^matiasmasso.pt$"  ignoreCase="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.matiasmasso.pt/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
      </rule>
      
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: "It does not happen if the url appends any segment like http://www.matiasmasso.pt/test it successfully opens https://www.matiasmasso.pt/test" is an indicator of possible browser side caches. Follow the answer below for further analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rules you posted do not cause http://www.matiasmasso.pt to redirect to https://www.matiasmasso.es, clear the cache and test again.

If you still can't solve the problem, you can use the [failed request trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view the detailed request process, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: Use a privacy tab of the browser is usually enough. Clearing caches is rather complicated so not really recommended for quick testing/verification.